# How to parse json correctly in ios?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

For example I need to get all english "text" values of "ex" scope from [JSON example](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqwqBqQf0Y7zmwNMQY7EV28zlN4V)
What I do:

```
let result = json["def"].arrayValue.map({ $0["tr"].arrayValue.map { $0["ex"] } })
```

but at as a result I got a double massive and if I intend to get all "text" then I will get a triple array. Guess should be another more elegant approach to this task. Is anyone can show a really good solution?

Comment: The problem is that you are not really parsing. You are attempting to do some operations on unparsed data. To simplify your code, first create objects and parse data into objects. Once you have objects, the code will become much simpler and also type safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expression gives 3 arrays of Strings you could add `.reduce([], +)` at the end to join the 3 arrays into
one.

### EDIT:

I was typing from memory, and said the wrong thing. You would use reduce, not joined.

```
let result = json["def"]
  .arrayValue
  .map({ $0["tr"].arrayValue.map { $0["ex"] } })
  .reduce([], +)
```

That should give you what you want.

### EDIT #2:

The reduce function operates on sequences (like arrays). It takes an "initial result" value that seeds the process, and then a closure that operates on 2 elements, and returns a result. (a "binary" closure)
The `+` operator is actually a binary closure in Swift. It takes 2 elements and returns a single result, so you can simply pass in `+` instead of a closure. For arrays, `+` returns the result of combining the arrays.

So when you use reduce() on an array of arrays, and `[]` as the initial result, it combines `[]` with the first array, then the result of each `+` operator with the next entry in the array.

Take this simplified code for example:

```
//Start with an array of arrays of strings
let arrays = [
  ["string1", "string2", "string3"],
  ["string4", "string5", "string6"],
  ["string7", "string8", "string9"]
]

//First loop through the outer arrays and log their contents
for (index, object) in arrays.enumerated() {
  print("array[\(index)] = \(object)")
}

//Now combine the outer arrays into a single array
let combined = arrays.reduce([], + )

//Now print the entries in the combined array
print("\n---- combined arrays ----")
for (index, object) in combined.enumerated() {
  print("array[\(index)] = \(object)")
}
```

That produces the following output:

```
array[0] = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
array[1] = ["string4", "string5", "string6"]
array[2] = ["string7", "string8", "string9"]

---- combined arrays ----
array[0] = string1
array[1] = string2
array[2] = string3
array[3] = string4
array[4] = string5
array[5] = string6
array[6] = string7
array[7] = string8
array[8] = string9
```

Comment: I guess you mean `.joined()`?

Comment: I don't understand how to employ joined() method, but I made this 'let temp = json["def"].arrayValue.map({ $0["tr"].arrayValue.map { $0["ex"].arrayValue.map { $0["text"].stringValue } } })
        let res = temp.flatMap { $0 }.flatMap { $0 }'

Comment: Actually, I was typing from memory and remembered wrong. The operator I meant to suggest was reduce. See the edit to my answer.